# ! Package babel Error: Language definition file armenian.ldf not found

Tags: hyphenation, languages, babel

I'd like to use hyphenation with armenian language.
Here is my test code (the armenian text is in utf8).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english,armenian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode}
\selectlanguage{armenian}
հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական 
\end{document}
```

I'm using recent txlive 2012 and compiling my tex using xelatex command.
I'm getting the following error:
    ! Package babel Error: Language definition file armenian.ldf not found.

```
See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.141 \ProcessOptions*
```

Is the armenian hyphenation not checked before and the armenian.ldf is really missing or I misconfigured the packages in  test.tex?

With thanks in advance,
Nerses

P.S. I didn't attached the log file, it makes the post too large.

Answer (score 6):

Babel has no Armenian language support by default. However, for `xelatex` use the package `polyglossia` instead. This works for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Code2000}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{armenian}
\begin{document} հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական 
 հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական
 հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական
 հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական  
\end{document}
```

I used the font `Code2000` because my Arial Unicode has no Armenian Script

Edit: I just realised, that polyglossia has also no hyphenation patterns for the Armenian language

Comment: Thanks Herbert, 

I used Your suggestion to use polyglossa. I slightly modifed by adding 
\setdefaultlanguage{armenian}
\newfontfamily\armenianfont{Arial Unicode}
and hyphenation started to work.

Thanks once more time,
Nerses

Answer (score 1):

Using Herbert's hint to use polyglossa I got the following working example which compiles with xelatex.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setdefaultlanguage{armenian}
\newfontfamily\armenianfont{Arial Unicode}

\begin{document}
հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական հասարակագիտական 
\end{document}
```